# how to make full height cell in full height table in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have next html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    html {height:100%;}body {height:100%;margin:0;}
    h1 {form-size:20px;margin:0;padding:20px;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <table style="width:100%;height:100%">
   <tr>
     <td>
       <div style="background-color:#f00;">
         <h1>This text should make height of this cell</h1>
       </div>
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr style="height:100%;" id="row">
     <td style="background-color:#c0c;">
       <div style="height:100%;width:100%;background-color:#00f;color:#fff;">
         This cell should take all unused space of table
       </div>
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>
       <div style="background-color:#0f0;">
        <h1>This text should make height of<br> this cell</h1>
       </div>
     </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

It works perfect in all browsers - except IE, where blue div inside middle cell takes space only for text.
May be someone know how to stretch it to whole free space inside table?

UPDATE: I Know that tables are bad in page-layout. if you can show me example of div layout which have top and bottom block with variable height and middle part which use all free space of browser window I will use it. I promise =)

Comment: Use divs. A page should'nt be made out of a table.

Comment: http://shouldiusetablesforlayout.com

Comment: if you can show me example of div layout which have top and bottom block with variable height and middle part which use all free space of browser window I will use it

Comment: I'll get working on it now ;)

Answer (score 8):

Don't use tables for layout please,

Use Divs and CSS, It is considered a bad practice to use tables:

[image: Tables]

http://shouldiusetablesforlayout.com

http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/

http://webdesign.about.com/od/layout/a/aa111102a.htm

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/article.php/3642151/CSS-Layouts-Without-Tables.htm

**[Live Demo converted to DIV's](http://jsfiddle.net/MR5xQ/6/)**

Comment: Show me div example with top and bottom with variable height. And I will use it, I promise.

Comment: @HenryPushel see above for demo

Comment: @Myles Gray: Didn't look at it too hard, but you should add `html, body { margin:0; padding:0 }`

Comment: @thirtydot Thanks, i was doing a P.O.C but I'll add that in now thanks!

Comment: you cheat. you make table without table. and it still doesn't work in ie7 =( But thank you

Comment: Can you add an IE7 screenshot? I'm on mac and thus don't have IE

Comment: @Myles Gray: http://ipinfo.info/netrenderer/ + Select IE7 + http://fiddle.jshell.net/MR5xQ/6/show/light/ = :) / :(

Comment: @thirtydot `/show/light` is awesome! I've got to find a Q of your's to vote up just because of that :D - It seems :| on that site, It sure does extend alright but I can't scroll down to see the footer :/

Comment: @Myles Gray: And there was me thinking you'd be impressed with the fast IE7 preview site :) `/show/light` is certainly very useful to get rid of all the jsFiddle clutter.

Comment: wow, you cheat twice %) You make whole row blue, so I thought that using table-* displays solve my problems in IE>7. Unfortunately it wasn't so. Pluses of this method is only semantic, but it doesn't matter, because all this code is generated by JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

If you define a `height` for the `body` element then the blue cell does expand to fill the available space ([JS FIddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/WKfqy/)). The problem is that an element of `height: 100%` takes up the full height of its *parent*, and for that to happen the browser has to know (be told) what the height of that parent element *is*.

You could achieve this with JavaScript ([JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/WKfqy/2/)) (or any one of the various libraries, eg jQuery: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/WKfqy/3/)<sup>1</sup>), or by using:

```
table {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/WKfqy/1/)

---

1. I have no idea why using the jQuery version results in scrolling. I've tried removing `padding`, `margin` etc from the various elements (`body` and `table`), but it results in the same behaviour. Which is a tad weird, to me.

Comment: @Henry, please note that while I answered the question (because it helps you (and me, of course) learn *something*), I *cannot* recommend using `table` s for layout. Please, I urge you, consider @Myles' advice to use `div`-based layouts, or, possibly even better, learn to use [html5](http://html5doctor.com/) elements for layout *and* semantics.

Comment: +1 for HTML5 and semantics, @DavidThomas he seems to be concerned about IE7 so I think semantics are the least of his worries, thought advisable if he is designing for a pro-IE audience then he should focus on just making it work in the first place, we all know what IE is like...

Answer (score 0):

Using `<div>` should be something like this:

```
<div style="width:100%;height:100%;background-color:#00f;color:#fff;">

    <div style="background-color:#f00;">
        <h1>This text should make height of this cell</h1>
    </div>

    This cell should take all unused space of table


    <div id="footer" style="background-color:#0f0; position:absolute; bottom:0px;width:100%;">
        <h1>This text should make height of<br> this cell</h1>
    </div>

</div>
```

The content in the center is not within a `<div>`, but in the main `<div>` itself. :)