# HTML table background

Tags: html, css

How are you doing?

am having a little difficulty writing my first HTML website! am stuck on a little few details that I would really appreciate it if you guys help me a little bit with, again this is my first time I write HTML so I apologize is my mistakes and questions are kinda trivial.

here are my questions:

am trying to make a green background at the top of the page, but I cant figure out how, I tired using bgcolor to color the row where the table sits on but that doesnt seem to work.

Here is what I tired to do:

```
<tr bgcolor = "green">
        <table width = "50%">
            <tr>
                <td><a href = "http://www.google.com"> Home </a></td>
                <td><a href = "http://www.google.com> About Us </a></td>
                <td><a href = "http://www.google.com> Products </a></td>
                <td><a href = "http://www.google.com> Services </a></td>
                <td><a href = "http://www.google.com> Contact Us </a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </tr>
```

another problem when trying to write something next to the input fields (the username password input fields); when trying to write "Office all is an internet store that...", instead of appearing right next to the input fields they appear under them!

here is what I did

```
<tr>
        <td>
            <form action = "processor.class" method = "get">
                User Name:
                <p/>
                <input type = "text"  name = "txtName" size = "10" />
                <p/>
                Password: 
                <p/>
                <input type = "password" name = "txtPassword" size = "10" />
                <p/>
                <input type = "submit" value = "Login"/> <a href = "http://www.jce.ac.il"> Register account</a>
            </form>
        </td>

        <td>
        office all is an internet...
        </td>

    </tr>
```

Can you help me out please?

thanks =)

**EDIT: thank you guys for your help, as u all suggested I will try to read a CSS tutorial and stop using tables, I will close this thread now and open it when and if I have more questions to ask (after i learn a lil more about CSS)**

Comment: wondering why tables and not plain html/css ...

Comment: Use css to apply the `background-color: green;`, rather than the `bgcolor` attribute.

Comment: ...didn't think about it to be quite honest, as i said this is the first time i write in HTML/CSS

Comment: "I will close this thread now and open it when and if I have more questions" -- StackOverflow is not a message board. If you have a new question, create another question.

Comment: oh k, sorry about that, still new here =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wherever you are learning web development from, dump that book/tutorial/whatever and pick up something a little more recent.  Using tables to lay out pages is a very poor way of doing things.  If you are just learning web development, you should be learning how to lay out pages with CSS, not tables.

Answer (score 2):

Oh dear.. tables... Educate yourself here:

[how to make full height cell in full height table in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004665/how-to-make-full-height-cell-in-full-height-table-in-internet-explorer/5004820#5004820)

Once you have read that take a look here:

http://htmldog.com/guides/cssbeginner/

You will find in the long run using semantic HTML and meaningful CSS will greatly reduce your workflow and make your sites much more x-browser compatible.

At the minute wherever you are learning from is hindering your progress and will not help you to achieve your goals, best dump that and stick with good sources like HTMLDog (Avoid W3Schools like the plague - http://w3fools.com)

Comment: thanks for the tip =), I will avoid w3schools

Answer (score 1):

Looks like others have given answers to your problems. However, for better structuring of your pages I suggest you to read http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/08/from-table-hell-to-div-hell/

Answer (score 1):

You should be using CSS to specify background colours and styles.

Using tables for layout is a bad idea, and there are several other naive mistakes in your code (ie. `<p/>` is wrong)

I suggest you find tutorials on basic HTML and CSS. Perhaps the [beginner tutorial at HTML Dog](http://htmldog.com/guides/htmlbeginner/) will help you. There are [working examples](http://htmldog.com/examples/textarea.html) for forms.

Answer (score 1):

Google : CSS Table Designs

the result from [Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/08/13/top-10-css-table-designs/) would help you fix this.

Comment: will check it out now, thank u

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, I would spend a few hours looking at w3schools reading about css and html

[W3Schools css](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp)
[W3Schools html](http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp)

Below is a very rough way to get the layout you want. Note the use of a horizontal list instead of a table, and the use of css.

I have still used a few tables, and they should really be replaced with css as well..

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
  ul 
  {
    background-color:green;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin-top:0;
    margin-bottom:0;
    padding-top:1em;
    padding-bottom:1em;
  }

  li
  {
    display:inline; 
    text-: white;
  }

  td
  {
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  </ul>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <form action = "processor.class" method = "get">
          <div>
            User Name: <input type = "text"  name = "txtName" size = "10" />
          </div>
          <div>
           Password: <input type = "password" name = "txtPassword" size = "10" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <input type = "submit" value = "Login"/> <a href = "http://www.jce.ac.il"> Register account</a>
          </div>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>
          office all is an internet...
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

the first problem you can use css it's more efficient way

and for the second problem you should put the text in "label" tag inside the "p"

tag that contains the input

Answer (score -2):

Try putting bgcolor in the nested `<table>` tag rather than the `<tr>` tag.  It's invalid code as well, since there is no `<td>` inside the `<tr>`.

A better way would be to use CSS.  It's harder to wrap your head around, but it's much easier in the long run.