# valign not working on a td?

Tags: html, css, html-table, valign

I have a table that contains a form, in the left col is the name of the field, and i would like to set the text to the top of the td, as at the moment the text is at the bottom.

Does any one know why this is a hit and miss element attribute?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Firstly,

You shouldn't really be using tables for layout (even for forms) you should use `div`s and CSS:
[how to make full height cell in full height table in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004665/how-to-make-full-height-cell-in-full-height-table-in-internet-explorer/5004820#5004820)

Secondly,

`valign` was deprecated, we now use the css property `vertical-align` see why not to use `valign`:
http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html

HMTL:

`<div class="className">Blah</div>`

CSS:

```
.className {
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```