# setting valign property of <TD> in javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [valign not working on a td?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214151/valign-not-working-on-a-td)

I'm adding rows to a table dynamically using javascript as following:

```
var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
var iteration = lastRow;
var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);

var cellLeft = row.insertCell(0);
var inc = parseInt(iteration)+1;
var textNode = document.createTextNode(inc);
cellLeft.appendChild(textNode);

var cellMiddle = row.insertCell(1);
var el = document.createElement('input');
el.type = "checkbox";
cellMiddle.appendChild(el);

var cellRight = row.insertCell(2);
var el1 = document.createElement('span');
el1.innerHTML = "asdasd adad a aa a a s a a a  a as "+
           " a a as a a a  adasdadsadad ad ada aasdasd as aas  ";
```

Here I create a row with 3 columns one showing number, second contains checkbox and third one contains data. Here the data in 3rd column is very long and that's why it's height increases and checkbox and number in other cells are shown in middle. I want to set there valign proprty to top. How can I do that?

I've tried following line but did not worked:

```
cellLeft.valign="top";
```

Comment: tried css? `cellLeft.style.verticalAlign = "top"` ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214151/valign-not-working-on-a-td

Comment: Yes it works. Thanks. You should post it as an answer.

Comment: you should search this site before posting a question. It was an answer from an identical question.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this using following javascript code :

```
cellLeft.style.verticalAlign = "top";
```

Comment: +1 for actually answering the question