# Why does valign="bottom" not work in firefox, and works in IE and Chrome?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have this template that is used on all pages.

```
<table CELLPADDING=0; CELLSPACING=0; style="width:100%; min-height:100vh;">
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align:top;">
            [EP_CA:Header]
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="align:center; vertical-align:top; width:100%;">
            [EP_CA:Menu]
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="align:center; vertical-align:top; width:100%;">
            [EP_CA:SiteMap]
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="align:center; vertical-align:top; width:100%; height:100%">
            [EP_CA:Body]
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="footerBottom" style="vertical-align:bottom;">
            [EP_CA:Footer]
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I tried display="block" for the footer td but that did not work either.

EDIT:I'm trying to align the footer row to the bottom of the page, even if the content is less. That code works for chrome it's just firefox that's not responding.

Comment: Any reason you're not using `flex` for this?

Comment: [Here you go](https://jsfiddle.net/r8zh9LLu/)

Comment: Nowadays your should use CSS for styling your web page, using HTML attributes is not recommend for more than 10 years.

Comment: I tried that in css also. does not work.

Comment: Your HTML gave me flashbacks to FrontPage-generated table layouts circa 1999. It has no place on the Internet today. Use CSS. **Do not use tables for page layout!**

Comment: Dai: I have used css. I guess it's the tables that's not allowing to align.

Comment: Niet: This is an old site which I'm upgrading. I will try it[flex] out.

Comment: [CSS 2.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#propdef-min-height), still the latest version of table layout spec usable, says: "In CSS 2.2, the effect of 'min-height' and 'max-height' on tables, inline tables, table cells, table rows, and row groups is undefined." Firefox behaviour is therefore not wrong, just different. Use `height` rather than `min-height` on your table. By the way, cellpadding and cellspacing are not CSS properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed min-height:100vh to height:100vh.
It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using HTML5, valign will not work.

Use CSS.

Comment: I have used a class to the footer tag which implements vertical-align. It still does not align it to the bottom of page.

Comment: Please share the snippet. It will be easier to analyze. A small suggestion, during designing, don't check for the output browser or device wise. Have a check in your code about the property/tag you are using. Many properties are supported by Chrome but not by Firefox, there are many those are supported by Firefox but not by Safari. Many properties have been terminated in HTML5 etc etc. Every browsers have their own way to bypass the missing properties. In this way, you will get confused. Go for browser/device check during testing phase.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I actually included the css inside the html tags.(which are related to the layout.)
And I'm able to get answer to why only firefox?(the root cause.) I have used basic designing, which is accepted by other browsers.

Answer (score -2):

Using CSS you should apply vertical-align. [valign not working on a td?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214151/valign-not-working-on-a-td)

```
td {vertical-align:top;}
```

Comment: Using the CSS equivalent of something that doesn't work, isn't going to work either.

Comment: It's deprecated

Comment: So what? Browser still support it for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Oh really?  That's awesome!

Comment: I have tried that. All variations I could possible think of.

Answer (score -3):

For cross-browser compatablity, I suggest you not use the table property and use  instead...

```
<div> Header </div>
<div> Menu </div>
<div> SiteMap </div>
<div> Body </div>
<div position:relative; bottom:0px;"> Footer </div>
```

Comment: @Darshan What are you trying to accomplish? Valign might not be the best option...

Comment: I'm trying to align the footer row to the bottom of the page, even if the content is less.
That code works for chrome it's just firefox that's not responding.