# Nested Table IE/Safari/Chrome Display Issue

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari

I have a pair of nested tables which seem to work fine in Firefox, but in IE, Chrome and Safari, the display is all messed up.

Basically, the outer table is defined as having width=100%, and then each row in that table contains another table, which also has width=100%. Each inner table also contains one row, with the widths of all but one cell being defined as x number of pixels, and the last cell being defined without a width (so that it should fill the balance.

In Firefox this works exactly as I expect - the cell with the unspecified width occupies the remainder of the row. However, in IE, Safari and Chrome, the cell without a width seems to get a 0px width, and the other cells in the table split the remainder of the space.

The code can be seen over [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QzxrL/) (JSFiddle).

Comment: Have you tried putting a non-breaking space in the empty cell? (&nbsp;)

Comment: yes - it then forces the height to be a minimum of a certain amount of space, and doesn't fix the problem with the width. The height I could deal with by making the text super small, but if it doesn't help the width display...

Comment: Why Why Why are you using tables for a layout?? Thats your first problem.

Comment: Did you look at the layout that I posted on JSFiddle? Doing this with divs would be much more effort, and the layout actually is a table-like structure.

Comment: It worked for me in Chrome - and yeah you'll have to set your font-size and line-height to 0

Comment: @Elie I looked at it in JSFiddle.. its not tabular data, therefore its an improper use of tables.

Comment: @Infotekka thanks! Post that as an answer and I'll mark it correct. I had to make some other small changes, but it worked.

Comment: @Loktar lay it out visually, see the lines formed by the various table cells, and you will see that it is, in fact, a complete grid.

Comment: @Elie I agree with @Loktar that is in no way tabular data, *your doing it wrong* it doesn't matter if it is "looks" tabular that look can be emulated EASILY with div's and CSS - [check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004665/how-to-make-full-height-cell-in-full-height-table-in-internet-explorer/5004820#5004820)

Comment: @Myles I looked at your post, and while I would agree that in general using tables for layouts is wrong, this happens to be a case where it's actually simpler to get the right design with tables than with div's and css. Accessibility is not an issue in this particular case, nor are many of the arguments shown in one of the links in your post, for a variety of non-visible reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take these three steps on each of the cells do not have a width set:

- Add a non-breaking space. (`&nbsp;`)
- Set `line-height:0;`
- Set `font-size:0;`

I went through your fiddle and did this on the third cell in each row, except for the one with the actual content in it, and it rendered correctly.