# CSS/HTML: What is the "right" way to create this effect?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, w3c

I'm working on a website for a small law office.  There's a menu bar across the top that I want to be equi-spaced with a | between each item:
[Link](http://www.richardmeinderslaw.com).  (The white bar just below the title banner)

This looks exactly right, but I'm using tables to accomplish it. Is there a "more correct" method for doing this with XHTML/CSS?

My code is below:

```
<div id="topMenu" class="spanningMenu">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="topMenuEnd"></td>
                <td class="topMenuMiddle"><a href="index.htm">Home</a></td>
                <td class="topMenuMiddle">|</td>
                <td class="topMenuMiddle"><a href="contact.htm">Contact Us</a></td>
                <td class="topMenuMiddle">|</td>
                <td class="topMenuMiddle"><a href="directions.htm">Directions</a></td>
                <td class="topMenuMiddle">|</td>
                <td class="topMenuMiddle"><a href="disclaimer.htm">Disclaimer</a></td>
                <td class="topMenuEnd"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.spanningMenu {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 4px 0px;
    padding: .2em;
}

#topMenu td.topMenuMiddle {
    width: 12.5%;
}

#topMenu td.topMenuEnd {
    width: 6.25%;
}
```

I like my solution because it's pretty robust, but it definitely has layout information in the HTML, which I've been trying to avoid.

Comment: Do you need something "dynamic" (will adjust itself if you add more items), or would you simply like a more semantic way to achieve the exact same thing visually?

Comment: *ul/ol* and css can do this well -- for static widths anyway (avoid a *div* as this really is a *list* structure). Take out the margins and use `display:block-inline` or, if you need to support IE6, keep it as it is :P

Comment: @pst: You're thinking of `display: inline-block` (for future reference).

Comment: @thirtydot: Dynamic would be great, but not necessary. I don't mind having to change a few numbers if I add another item.  Compatibility is going to be very important; it's a law office that deals with the elderly.

Comment: @JoshuaD: Does this need to work in IE6? Also, I assume it has to work in IE7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just hacked something together to give you an idea. It's a method I always use. You can adjust the width to suit your needs. Here's a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/pfkgw/

```
#menu {
    background:#ECD8B1;
    overflow:auto;
    border-top: 2px solid white;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
    padding: 5px 0px;
}
ul li {
    width: 24%;
    border-right:1px solid #000;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
}

ul li.last {
    border-right:none;
}

li a {
    display:block;
    padding:5px;
    color:#000;
}

<div id='menu'>
    <ul>
        <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Directions</a></li>
        <li class='last'><a href='#'>Disclaimer</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Firstly, you have `padding;5px`, with a semicolon instead of a colon in the middle (also, there's a semicolon missing at the end of that line). And, I know this is picky, but your use of `width: 24%` means there is some (uneven) unused space at the right edge. I know that if you put `width: 25%`, the `1px` borders will push the last button down due to the combined `width: 100% + borders`. The easiest solution is to put the borders on the `<a>` tags instead (along with a couple of other tweaks).

Comment: @thirtydot, yup you're absolutely right about the widths. Only put it in there because the fiddle wouldn't work otherwise. Since the OP mentioned that he can give exact widths to the links I let it be. I've fixed the typos that you mentioned as well.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, Tables for layout is wrong, tables for MENUS is just perverse...

[Please please please read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004665/how-to-make-full-height-cell-in-full-height-table-in-internet-explorer/5004820#5004820)

You should be doing this:

#### HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item1 |</li>
    <li>Item2 |</li>
    <li>Item3</li>
</ul>
```

#### CSS:

```
ul li {
    float:left;
    margin-left:5px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Mutant_Tractor/wyQFb/

Comment: This is not the desired functionality.  I understand that would work if I wanted the items to collapse, but I want them to spread out to the side of the page, and be equi-distance apart regardless of the width of the contained text.  I'm looking into inline-block formatting, which might be the trick.

Comment: I'm not sure how tables can be argued against when `float` is used -- it's just as perverse a hack for the hopefully-nobody-uses-them-anymore-browsers :)

Comment: As an aside, the insulting language is uncalled for, especially considering I came here saying "I know this is the wrong way, what's the right way?"

Comment: @JoshuaD but you were mentioning using style elements in the HTML, which fair enough is wrong but no where near as bad as using a structural element (Table) for non tabular data. Also use `padding-left/right: whatever px;` to do it.

Comment: @pst I would have used `<nav>` but IE6 and Netscape dont like that :P

Comment: @JoshuaD If you are targeting *non-quirks* IE7+ (maybe IE6 with a few "tweaks") browsers, try just a UL with `display:inline-block`. Perhaps in the future all the `table` displays can be used reliably as well ;-) I'm not sure what equidistance means here. Add a MSPaint drawing to the post?

Comment: @pst: the website I linked to works perfectly, it's just "bad design".  Equidistance means that, in my example, the cells are all the same size.

Answer (score 1):

It is generally accepted that a navigation bar is a list of links, so it should be in `<ul></ul>` tags.

I would not include the pipe character `|` because that is *also* presentational. You can add it in the CSS using `li:after { content: "|"; }` or by adding a CSS `border` attribute.

For information on styling up lists horizontally, check out [Listamatic](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<style type="text/css">
#menu { width: 100%; }
#menu a { display: block; float: left; width: 20%;
border-right: 1px solid #000; text-align: center; }
#menu a.last { border-right: 0px solid #000; clear: both; }
</style>

<div id="menu">
<a href="/">Link 1</a>
<a href="/">Link 2</a>
<a href="/" class="last">Link 3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: That might do the trick, I'll let you know.  @Myles: where are the tables in his solution?  :Confused:

Comment: @JoshuaD he's talking about using the correct markup for the correct role

Comment: Of course an ul-tag could be used for the menu... it is the same concept (floating etc.)