# How to Create Full size HTML Tables? (No margins, Full Window)

Tags: browser, html-table, html

I want to create a basic two columns layout in HTML with a table, but I want the table to "occupy" the FULL PAGE. without margins ("white spaces" between borders and browser's window), let me be more clear with an example:

```
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>Pagina nueva 4</title>
<meta name="Microsoft Theme" content="none">
</head>

<body>

<table border="4" width="100%" height="567" style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 3px solid #FF0000" bordercolorlight="#FF0000">
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="#008080">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="160" bgcolor="#000000">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
   </table>

   </body>

   </html>
```

As you can see there, we have a green table with a black sidebar and red borders, all on top of a white background. The thing is, I want the borders to be "absolute" without having white space between user's browser window and them. I want the table to occupy the Full Page without spaces or "margins" or whatever they are, sorry for being redundant.

How can I do that?

Comment: `body{margin:0px;padding:0px}` in CSS? And `width:100%` in the table??

Comment: [Read this please :)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004665/how-to-make-full-height-cell-in-full-height-table-in-internet-explorer/5004820#5004820)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>Pagina nueva 4</title>
<style>
  body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
  }
  .container {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 567px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 3px solid #FF0000;
  }
  .container .content {
    background-color: #008080;
  }
  .container .sidebar {
    background-color: #000000;
    width: 160px;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>

<table class="container">
<tr>
    <td class="content">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="sidebar">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also found another way to do it, here's the sample code (Comments in Spanish):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Tabla ajustable al navegador y colunma fija de 200px</title>
<style type="text/css">
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
#tabla {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #444;
    background-color: #ffc;
}
.celda_dcha {
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #444;
    background-color: #cfc;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<!-- los bordes y colores son para testar la maqueta -->
<!-- este esquema se adapta a cualquier resolución de pantalla, conservando la columna de la derecha siempre los 200px -->
<!-- probado en iexplorer 7 y 8, ff 3.6, opera 10 y safari 5 -->
<table id="tabla">
    <tr>
        <td>Contenido</td>
        <td class="celda_dcha">Columna para imágenes</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: nice work.  Be careful with the '*' in your css.  It can sometimes have different effects in different browsers depending on how it's used.

Comment: Another question: That code I wrote up there worked quite fine... The only problem I'm having it's that the right sidebar is not adjusting to different screen resolutions, I mean, it adjust until "1080px" height aprox, but when you go out with 1200px the bar separates from the footer (Yep, I have a footer too) the left side of the table doesn't seem to be afected at all, it looks fine in all screens, the footer adjusts itself to resolutions changes too, but the right sidebar or right "column" of the table don't why? Hope you can help.

Comment: I would have to see your code.  A table should never 'separate' itself when changing browser widths.  The table should expand but the sidebar won't get bigger width-wise as it is set to a fixed width.

Comment: @RDL it was a Doctype issue, solved it by myself: http://goo.gl/hxdhH there's the question I opened for that problem with the answer I found. Thanks! ;)