# How do I vertically align a content div between a header and footer div?

Tags: css, xhtml, vertical-alignment

I have three rows of primary divs in my template.  I have a header, a content wrapper, and a footer.  The header butts right up against the top and the footer against the bottom.  I have a content wrapper div in between the two.  I basically want to center the content wrapper vertically within the two divs.  The content div will always be a dynamic height, so the line-height method won't work for me.  What would be the best method for me to use for this?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004665

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Vertically centering content**

Without using JavaScript, there's a limited number of ways to vertically center dynamic content:

1. [HTML tables](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html)
2. [CSS tables](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html)
3. [CSS3 flexbox](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/)
4. [CSS3 grids](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-grid-layout/)

In a case like this, the modern approach is to use CSS tables, which is equivalent to HTML tables. But if support for IE7 or earlier is needed, then use HTML tables instead. Flexbox isn't a good fit in this particular case, and it's not supported by IE9 and earlier. CSS grids are only supported by IE10 at present, and the standard hasn't been finalized.

The basic usage of CSS tables is:

**HTML**

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.table {display: table;}
.row   {display: table-row;}
.cell  {display: table-cell;}
```

**Demos**   (tested in: IE8/9/10, FF, Chrome, Safari, Opera)

- [HTML tables](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/y6sbt/)
- [CSS tables](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/XyX2T/)

**Choosing between HTML tables and CSS tables**

For *tabular data* (e.g., a grid of data), favor using *HTML tables*. It's more semantically correct in this case, and the nature of the source code can be more easily understood, which may help with accessibility and SEO (and the maintainability of the code).

For *non-tabular data* (e.g., general layout), favor using *CSS tables* (if floats and CSS positioning are not adequate). It's more semantically correct, since the use of HTML tables creates an expectation of tabular data, and it may be less confusing to screen readers and search engines. Specific uses for layout include vertically-centered content and equal-height columns.

One particular advantage of CSS tables over HTML tables is the support for `visibility:collapse`, which allows rows or columns to collapse (something not doable with HTML tables). If there's a need for that specific feature for tabular data, use CSS tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the following code:-

```
<div> using display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle
```

Comment: All that does is it realigns my content div to the left and it nullifies the width of it.

Comment: This is not a complete css code you have to add other css code, the above code only certical center the content not anything else

Comment: @ShoeLace1291: `display:table-cell` is the preferred approach for modern browsers. @Chase1986: +1 for steering things in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Save yourself some pain and just break them out into three separate containers.

```
#header {
    width:1000px; /* or what ever width you need */
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    clear:both;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#content{
    width:1000px; /* or what ever width you need */
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    clear:both;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#footer{
    width:1000px; /* or what ever width you need */
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    clear:both;
    overflow:hidden;
}

<div id="header">test</div>
<div id="content">test</div>
<div id="footer">test</div>
```

The overflow hidden attribute will make a div expand automatically to show any additional content that is added to it.. making it behave more like a table cell.

Here is an example [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/FKnpM/)

Comment: This addresses horizontal centering, but the question is about vertically centering the main content on the page.

Comment: Vertically centering content in divs can get tricky as there is no easy way to do it like there is with a table cell.  You can wrap your content in a child div and then use margin-top.  http://jsfiddle.net/FKnpM/2/

Comment: Historically speaking, yes, but in modern browsers, CSS table layout provides an easy way to do this with a div. See the answer I posted for additional info.

Comment: You could use div tables but personally I don't use them.  There is no real benefit to using them aside from real tables so it kind of defeats the purpose of building a site in CSS.  Div tables add code, have rigid structure (like a normal HTML table) and can fall prey to the same cross browser issues that regular table layouts do.

Comment: Did some additional research. Choosing between the two is mostly about semantic correctness and whether support for `visibility:collapse` is needed. I added info about this to my answer.