# Horizontally center a div with CSS

Tags: css

So, on my website I'm trying to make this here http://prntscr.com/vk3cv.
The text, as you can see, isn't centered. I have the following code in my HTML
http://prntscr.com/vk3iy, and this in my CSS prntscr.com/vk3ml.

But, it doesn't seem to center it. I have had a friend help me out with that code.
The code I had before made it was just aligned to the left. I was wondering how would I make it so that it is completely centered?

In the code I had before, the html was changed from `DIV class="row"`
to `DIV class="row feature"`

And in CSS I didn't have that `feature` thing added.

Comment: Could you post the code that you tried?

Comment: the code that i tried is the code their, the code i had before was <div class="row"> and it didn't have the css code i showed.

Comment: hi please share your html and css code here so that we can help you.just sending images of problem we can't do anything..you can use this http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1):

**The basic options**

1. Give the container a fixed width and `margin:0 auto;`
2. Put the container in an HTML table cell (or a similar set of nested divs using CSS tables) and give the table cell `text-align:center;`
3. Use JavaScript or jQuery

If the container has a variable width, then you'll need #2 or #3.

If you decide on #2, it's more semantically-correct to use CSS tables in this case (favor HTML tables for data grids, and CSS tables for layout) (see [the last few paragraphs here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15206968/1306809)). Both are a reasonable option. But if you need support for IE7 or earlier, then you'll have to use HTML tables.

**Auto margin**

```
.feature {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.feature .3u {
    width: 200px;
}
```

**CSS table**

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Content goes here</div>
    </div>
</div>
...
.table   {display: table;}
.row     {display: table-row;}
.cell    {display: table-cell;   text-align: center;}
.feature {display: inline-block; text-align: left;    width: auto;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `text-align: center;` in the stylesheet in the div that is used to hold the text, to center the text.

Comment: all it did was center the text as seen here http://prntscr.com/vk4p4 but what im trying to do is make it center the 3 columns with the entire webpage how would i go about doing that?